# If using Expresso Store, is it possible to feature products in non-store pages? Is there a way to feature "related products"?

Tags: expresso-store

Maybe a dumb question, but I have zero experience with Expresso Store. Since products are channel entries, is it possible to 1) feature products in non-store pages (say the homepage) and 2) use categories or relationships in order to show products related to the product the user is viewing?

Bonus question: Are the expensive SSL certificates with the green URL background worth the $$? How low can I go with SSL costs and still be secure?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid asking two questions here, it makes it hard to upvote the best answer for each. You're more than welcome to start separate threads (although discussing SSL certificates may be deemed as off-topic since it's not really EE-related) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can display them anywhere on the site, as you say they're just entries. Obviously you'll need to include the store product tags to output the price details or any modifiers if required.

Due to EE's flexibility there are many ways to display featured or related products, some of the easiest is to use a category, [relationships](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) or I'd recommend using [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa), or a combination of each of them depending on what you require.

For example, I use Playa on product entries so the client can simply choose by dragging and dropping the other products that they want to up-sell on that page (related). Same on the homepage, a "featured" Playa field that the client can select 30 (say) products and the homepage outputs 10 of these randomly keeping the content fresh.

**Bonus Answer**: Depending on the browser you get different display of the padlock and the more expensive SSLs will also display differently - so not always that prominent.

[image] 
Example [reference](http://www.digicert.com/ev-ssl-certification.htm) (no recommendation - just first result from Google!)

Besides the additional display, these types of SSL show the owner of the SSL. Most consumers/visitors wouldn't have a clue regarding the difference this made and doubtful they'd even understand that an SSL could be registered by a different company from the owners of the website.

Personally as a developer, I wouldn't recommend to a client as I don't think it's any more beneficial to them, especially at the cost. As a customer visiting a site, I'd be happy for just a normal padlock and security - as long as the site looked respectable, decent and trustworthy.